# Cant query sybase with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Have started to use NHibernate on sybase ASE data, problem am facing is when I load entity I get below error

"System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Invalid index 0 for this OdbcParameterCollection with Count=0."

This is how I configure session

```
properties["connection.provider"] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider";
properties["connection.driver_class"] = "NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver";
properties["connection.connection_string"] = @"Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=;port=; db=;uid=;pwd=";
properties["dialect"] = "NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect";
```

And object mapping

```
  <class name="MenuGroup" table="MENU_GROUP">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>    
    <property name="Name" column="name" type="String" length="100" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Position" column="position" type="Int32" />  
  </class>
```

and If I do

```
 var menuGroup = _session.Get<Menu.MenuGroup>(1);
```

I get error

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not load an entity: [DomainModel.Menu.MenuGroup#1][SQL: SELECT menugroup0_.id as id1_0_, menugroup0_.name as name1_0_, menugroup0_.position as position1_0_ FROM MENU_GROUP menugroup0_ WHERE menugroup0_.id=?]
  ----> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Invalid index 0 for this OdbcParameterCollection with Count=0.

Comment: I am having the same problem atm. I am trying to get my solution to work with NHibernate 3.2. What version are you using?

Comment: 3.2.0.4, any idea if changing to older version will help

Comment: well, our solution used to work with SQL Anywhere 10, but we migrated to 12 yesterday. I got that running with NHibernate 2.1.2 GA which was built on .net framework 2.0. Today I've started implementing NHibernate 3.2.0.4000 (3.2 GA), but now all my query unittests fail with the error you described.

Comment: try with NHibernate.Driver.SybaseSQLAnywhereDriver, it should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving away from odbc helped, changed the config to

properties["connection.provider"] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider";
        properties["connection.driver_class"] = "NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAseClientDriver";
        properties["connection.connection_string"] = @"server=****;port=5000; db=***;user id=****;password=***;";
        properties["dialect"] = "NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect";

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating my own connection driver

```
using NHibernate.Driver;

namespace Framework.Persistency
{
    public sealed class MySybaseSQLAnywhereDriver : SybaseSQLAnywhereDriver
    {
        public override bool UseNamedPrefixInSql
        {
            //default is false
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool UseNamedPrefixInParameter
        {
            //default is false
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override string NamedPrefix
        {
            //default is string.Empty
            get { return ":"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in the NHibernate config:

```
configDictionary.Add(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(MySybaseSQLAnywhereDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```